# Why does haskell's `fix` seem to have trouble with tuples?

Tags: haskell, fixpoint-combinators

I'm trying to bend my head around fixed points and recursive definitions.

This works:

```
>>> take 10 $ let x = (0:x) in x
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

This does the same thing, which makes sense given the definition of `fix`:

```
>>> take 10 $ fix (\x -> (0:x))
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Now suppose I start messing around with recursively defined pairs:

```
>>> take 10 $ fst $ let (u,v) = (0:v,1:u) in (u,v)
[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
```

Okay, I should be able to write that with `fix` too, right?

```
>>> take 10 $ fst $ fix (\(u,v) -> (0:v,1:u))
*** Exception: <<loop>>
```

But it doesn't work. Unless I make the following seemingly trivial change:

```
>>> take 10 $ fst $ fix (\r -> let (u,v)=r in (0:v,1:u))
[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
```

What's the critical difference between the last two examples?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want

```
take 10 $ fst $ fix (\ ~(u,v) -> (0:v,1:u))
                      ^^^
```

so as to make the pattern matching lazy. In `let`, the LHS pattern is implicitly lazy/irrefutable.

With the plain `\(u,v) -> ...` the argument of the lambda will be demanded before any output is produced -- this makes the function too strict for `fix`. What you need is something like

```
take 10 $ fst $ fix (\p -> (0:snd p,1:fst p))
```

so that the argument is not forced by the lambda (there's no constructor there to match). The lazy pattern approach is equivalent to the `fst/snd` above.

Comment: That should be `\(~(u,v))` or `\ ~(u,v)`

Comment: @redneb Fixed. (pun intended :-P)